# Laptop Freezes on Boot If Still Connected to Power

Tags: freeze, power, connection, reboot

**Toshiba Satellite P745**
Windows 7 Home and Ultimate (same happens with both versions).

My laptop **ALWAYS** hangs (just before entering Windows, on the '**welcome screen**') if it is plugged into the AC-Power from the last time I used the computer.

However if I disconnect the power cable and battery then plug it back in, then its fine.

It needs "releasing" from the power connection in order to enter Windows.
Something about remaining connected to the power cable or battery from the last time I used it will cause the computer to hang at the welcome screen.

But the second I switch off or restart or sleep my computer, then it will Hang or Freeze again the next time I switch it back on, unless I unplug the power cable and plug it back in again!

This happens every time, regardless if I use the battery or power-pack or both. I have no idea what is causing this.

If it hangs, then I need to do a hard switch off and it ruins my software registrations; many apps and software need reinstalling every time when I do the hard power off.

I have got a new hard drive; reinstalled Windows; bought a new battery and AC-Power Pack. The electricity supply to the laptop needs to be stopped or broken or unplugged so that it can start again successfully.

Is there any Windows Start-Up log I can view or install to see EXACTLY what part of the start-up process my computer hangs because this might help me find the problem.

- I tried disabling the AC-Adapter and ACPI battery (in the "Device Manager") but this did not help.
- Please let me know if you have any ideas for me.

Comment: Have you tried holding F8 and going into safe mode? When you turn the laptop off are you doing a proper shutdown or are you hibernating?

Comment: To determine either it is a Hardware or Software fault start by changing OS. Easiest way, download a Linux distro's ISO make a bootable Linux USB stick (all process takes 5-10minutes),boot into Linux Live CD ( suggest Ubuntu has the most robust driver base or Mint ), whil ebooting keep the Power plugged in and see what is happening. If all goes well and you boot, you can easily rule out a Hardware fault. Which means you need to address Your Laptop's Configuration, was it installed by hand ? was it a OEM install with all the OEM programs on etc ? Have you downloaded suggested software from OEM?